# Access table user in sysdba privilege

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, privilege, sysdba

I created some tables as a normal user, and when I change the privilege to sysdba I didn't fiund my tables!
I get this message: `table or view does not exist`

This is what I do:
First of all, with a normal user's privilege I create `tab1`:

```
create table tab1 …;
```

and I insert some values, when I

```
select * from tab1;
```

all my rows are displayed, but when I connect as sysdba; with this current user, no row is displayed!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you login as sysdba, you literally become the the sys user, and as such, you're connected to the sys schema, not your own:

```
sqlplus kjohnston as sysdba
*connected*
SQL> show user;
USER is "SYS"
```

Since you are in the sys schema, you have to reference your tables in your schema by prefixing the tablename with the schema name, as in:

```
select * from kati_ais.tab1;  //assuming kati_ais is your schema name
```

As a side note, you should not get in the habit of logging in as sysdba unless you really need those higher level privileges for that session.

Answer (score 0):

From the oracle documentation https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/dba.htm#ADMIN11048 , here's what sysdba provide to your user:

```
Perform STARTUP and SHUTDOWN operations

ALTER DATABASE: open, mount, back up, or change character set

CREATE DATABASE

DROP DATABASE

CREATE SPFILE

ALTER DATABASE ARCHIVELOG

ALTER DATABASE RECOVER

Includes the RESTRICTED SESSION privilege
```

What you need to see your tables with your other user is either:

```
grant select on *normal_user*.table1 to *your_sysdba_user*
```

and repeat it for each table

or you can go bar open with

```
grant select any table to *your_sysdba_user*
```

but be advised that select any table include everything from everyone including data dictionary view which may be more than you truly wish to allow

I would assume that your sysdba user would be close to database god like sys so that would be ok but the disclaimer is there so you know

Comment: Thanks for your response , but maybe you don't understand my question…
First of all, with a normal user's privilege I create tab1 create table tab1 … ;
and I insert some values, when I select * from tab1; all my rows are displayed, but when I put connect as sysdba; with this current user , not row display !!

Comment: Ok, i might have misunderstood indeed.  Did you commit the insert done by your normal privilege user?  Because inside your session if you add row to a table and then select from that table, you will see your added rows but until you commit the changes, they will remain invisible to the other users/sessions